# Why is the first line of the first textline not visible in the HTML5 canvas in the following example?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to use a canvas to display 40x25 text field.

In the example code, I use an 8px font and display a letter 'A' in each text-position. The first-pixel line of the first character line is not displayed. When I start the first loop at y=1 the problem seems to be solved but canvas coördinates start at 0,0.

why does this happen?

```js
var c = document.getElementById("screen");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "8px monospace";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
for (y = 0; y < 200; y = y + 8) {
 for (x = 0; x < 320; x = x + 8) {
   ctx.fillText("A", x, y)
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="screen" width="320" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: @dpap   thx for editing... but formatting the code seems to be a problem

Comment: I will do it again in a while :) Thanks for notifying me ;)

Comment: Unable to reproduce in Firefox or Chrome. Added a canvas border in css `canvas {border: 1px solid red;}` to see where the canvas edges are, but saw no evidence of any missing first pixel line in first character line. Are you doing something else not shown in the posted code?

Comment: @tractor53     No... and I use firefox. Are you saying that the first pixel line is present for you if you run the code snippet in the question above?

Comment: I saw no problem when running the code snippet. I copied it for local testing.  Minor changes were to  declare variables `x` and `y` and show  the next letter of the alphabet on each line - and yes there are twenty five lines, "A" through "Y", but no missing first pixel line. My OS is Windows and the monospace font is Courier New.  FWIW  Ii also appears to work in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @tractor53     Indeed... the line is not missing for Courier New... strange...

Comment: I also found this [example] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline) from mozilla where 0.5 is added to y...

Comment: The example on mozilla is probably to show lines occupying a canvas pixel row - a stroke width of one will color 1/2 a pixel on either side of the line. My guess it's the font you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer out of comments, it appears to be an issue with the font in use - it seems to be drawing above the "top" baseline (see below).

Here's the *slightly* modified version of the snippet that fails to show a problem using Courier New as the default monospace font in browser settings.

```js
"use strict";
var c = document.getElementById("screen");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "8px monospace";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
var charCode = "A".charCodeAt(0);
for (var y = 0; y < 200; y = y + 8, ++ charCode) {
 var char = String.fromCharCode( charCode);
 for (var x = 0; x < 320; x = x + 8) {
   ctx.fillText(char, x, y)
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="screen" width="320" height="200"></canvas>
```

---

*(Update)*

Setting the value of the context's `baseLine` property to "top" set the base line to the top of the "em" square ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline#Options));

This image from [this question about Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/274601) demonstrates what that can mean for drawing font glyphs

[image]

[Source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-textbaseline)

If the font draws above the top of the em square that part of the glyph will be not be rendered in the first line drawn on the canvas. The picture also implies that fonts can have an upper bounding line above the em box.

This appears to be the case for the font used on the Ubuntu system.  Note that "monospace" is a non specific font family, not a font. You can find the actual font used by entering "monospace" in the search box on Firefox's options page, and clicking the "advanced" button presented under fonts and colors.

Comment: @tractor53     On my system (firefox on Ubuntu-mate) your snippet still has the problem... It disappears (in both versions) when I change the font line to 
ctx.font = "8px monospace courier new";

Comment: No argument, it appears to be font-related, not the code or canvas issues. What font causes the trouble?

Comment: @tractor53     It seems like monospace is the culprit

Comment: @tractor53     The default font is DejaVu Sans Mono

Answer (score 0):

So like you said the canvas starts at 0,0 from the top left corner. However 0,0 is the very corner where the canvas starts so text will not be visible at this coordinate. If you count your A's you have one short both on the x axis and y axis. Think if you were to fill this with color starting at 0,0 would be coming from the very tip of the top left hand corner. To show all your A's you will want to start at coordinate 1,1.

Comment: I count 40x25 A's... starting at 1,1 solves the problem (like I said before) but I don't see why...